Material 3 Search Bar Not showing proper position
I am trying add Search Bar for my fragment but when I run my app and click on search bar it is opening search view below search is there any solution I want to use it with recycle view and room database
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".gallery.GalleryFragment">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/searchbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
            <!-- Screen content goes here. -->
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
            android:id="@+id/search_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/search" />

            <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:hint="@string/search"
                app:layout_anchor="@id/search_bar">
            </com.google.android.material.search.SearchView>
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>


import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.KeyEvent
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager

class GalleryFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentGalleryBinding

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        binding = FragmentGalleryBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.searchView.setupWithSearchBar(binding.searchBar)
        binding.apply {
            searchView.editText.setOnEditorActionListener { _, _, _ ->
                val query = searchView.editText.text.toString()
                searchView.hide()
                searchBar.setText(query)
                true
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}


This is what's happaning 
I am using this because i want to give sort and delete button with search bar

you are closing SearchBar before starting/creating SearchView
    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/search" /> !!!!

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
            ...

it's not parent-child relation, rather these Views re neighbours (one below another, like on your screen). this should be probably more like this:
    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar
        ... > not closing here

        <com.google.android.material.search.SearchView
        ... /> child of SearchBar, closed in here

    <com.google.android.material.search.SearchBar /> now closing bar

in other words: SearchView should be child of SearchBar, just like SearchBar is a child of AppBarLayout

I have tried it and found problem it was that appbar was suppos to finsh before searchview
but now i have space above search view how to remove it any idea?
image
